# How to import Data from a MariaDB Dump-File with Windows PowerShell

Tags: powershell, io-redirection

Im trying to import a dumpfile.sql in the Windows Powershell with:

```
mysql -u root -p --database=database < Backup.sql
```

but i get the following error:

```
At <script-path>:1 char:34
+ mysql -u root -p --database=database < Backup.sql
+                                      ~ 
The '<' operator is reserved for future use..
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RedirectionNotSupported
```

If i try to escape the "<"

```
mysql -u root -p --database=database ^< Backup.sql
```

I only get a list of all options.

Maybe the problem arose due to the update to Windows 11.

Comment: Please try to post error message in English. As an aside: `^` only serves as the escape character in `cmd.exe`, not in PowerShell (where it is `\``, the so-called backtick).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try to pipe the backup file to the `mysql` exe like this:

```
Get-Content 'Backup.sql' | mysql.exe -u root -p --database=database
```

Another option is to run it using `cmd` from powershell

```
& cmd /c "mysql.exe -u root -p --database=database < backup.sql"
```